# How a rangefinder works?

Tags: laser

The speed of light is too high so how does a laser rangefinder calculate such a short time taken by the light to come back?

Comment: What makes you think that the speed of light is too high?  Modern electonic devices are *really* fast.

Answer (score 3):

I know of two types of optical range finder. One type is "time of flight": it measures the time taken for a short pulse of light to return. For this to work properly, you need a very fast light source, and a fast detector.

Now it's not hard to get an LED with a rise time below 1 ns, and detecting light that quickly is pretty easy too - using for example a SiPM (silicon photomultiplier) one can get timing on the order of 10's of picoseconds (limited by the timing circuit and photon statistics - see for example slide 12 in [this presentation](http://muon.npl.washington.edu/exp/NewG2/private/CaloDesign/DigitalSiPM_Philips/Talk_NM1-4.PDF)). Using multiple pulses, one can further reduce the uncertainty (with the square root of the number of pulses) to almost any number you want. I have seen a demonstration where the time delay of a small optical pulse through an optical fiber was measured tens of thousands of times per second: just bending the wire changed the path length sufficiently that one could see the histogram of measured values move (by a fraction of a picosecond). So it's definitely possible.

The second method is one that has the potential of being much cheaper to implement - it doesn't require the high speed devices. I saw this method implemented in the early 80's. You modulate the output of an LED with a sinusoidal signal, and detect the phase difference between the emitted and received signal. Phase difference can be measured very accurately (again, averaged over many cycles). If you use a 100 MHz signal, a complete wave is 3 m long; so as your reflector moves 1.5 m, the round trip is 3 m and you get a full 360° phase shift. If you can measure a 1° phase shift, you have a precision of less than 1 cm - but your result is multi-valued (it could be 1.4, 2.9, 4.4, 5.9, ... etc). By repeating the measurement with a different frequency (preferably one that doesn't divide well into the other) you can get a second set of values - and then you can find the value that is common to both methods to get the exact range.

[Link to a homebrew project that implements this](http://hackaday.com/2014/02/28/homebrew-phase-laser-rangefinder/)

In short - speed of light is fast, but it's quite easy to build a good rangefinder with modern electronics. Even 30 years ago an undergraduate physics student could do it...

Comment: And if you chirp the sin wave, all sorts of neat things can be done :-).  BTW, pulse-timing laser rangefinders can be had for around $100. Apparently hunters and golfers love the gadget.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - yes, a chirp effectively is "a lot of frequencies one after the other", while a pulse is "all frequencies at once" and the last method I described is "a small number of discrete frequencies". The latter is easy to implement in an analog circuit - which made it the preferred solution in 1982. With a chirp you need a good way to add variable delay, or fast digitization followed by correlation. But if you can do that, it's very accurate.